# Check if Variable from Database blank

Tags: php, database, is-empty

My ultimate end game is to display a To-Do list for new affiliate users on my site (visiting certain instructional pages, etc). When the user visits a specific page, it will update the DB with a time stamp of that visit for that specific page. 
Where I'm having an issue is getting it to accuractly display if that specific "To Do" tasks has been completed.

I set the variable $todo1 which is the first task in the list.

```
$todo1 = mysql_query("SELECT todo_introvideo FROM users WHERE user_name='$loggedInUser->username'");
```

Then...

```
if (empty($todo1)) 
{ 
   echo "<img name='check' style='width:20px;' src='images/unchecked.jgp' />"; 
} 
else {
    echo "<img style='width:20px;' src='images/checked.jpg'";}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I'm setting $todo1 with the the query text itself and not the results of that query because no matter if there is a value in todo_introvideo or not, it echoes checked.jpg.

Please help explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
<?php
$todoTask = mysql_query("SELECT todo_introvideo FROM users WHERE user_name='$loggedInUser->username'");

if (mysql_num_rows($todoTask)>0) 
{ 
    echo "<img style='width:20px;' src='images/checked.jpg'";

}else{
    echo "<img name='check' style='width:20px;' src='images/unchecked.jgp' />"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your query

```
$todo1 = mysql_query("SELECT todo_introvideo FROM users WHERE user_name='$loggedInUser->username'");
```

the result whatever is generating is **FALSE** always that's why else part is executing for displaying **checked.jpg**. It may be because there is no row matching according to the **where** condition in  your code. Make sure that **$loggedInUser->username** is working fine in your database i.e. username exists.
Also you are using **empty()** in your code.

> It determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable
>   is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Check if that is working fine according to your requirement. To know more on **empty()** click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($todo1);

```
if ($num_rows>0) 
{ 
  echo "<img name='check' style='width:20px;' src='images/unchecked.jgp'/>"; 
} 
else {
    echo "<img style='width:20px;' src='images/checked.jpg'";
}
```